# Adding class each time an item is dropped?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Thanks for looking at this question in advance.

I'm using jQuery drag and drop for a project I'm doing at university and I'm looking to count each drop and change the class that is added on each drop.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$('#droppableChoking').droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        //reuse jQuery object
        var $this = $(this);

        //get object type
        var droppedObject = ui.draggable.data('object');

        //css reset
        $this.removeClass();
        $this.addClass("grape" + droppedObject);
        }

        //play drop sound
        audioClap.play();
    }
});
```

I've tried doing a loop and add the value of the count to the class to change it each time but I'm doing something wrong!

Comment: What should be class name look like?

Comment: you need to pass the class to be removed when you call removeClass()

Comment: Well, a loop isn't going to help, unless you could somehow put the user inside the loop, and if you could do that, JS is a much cooler language than I thought… But your idea of keeping a counter is on the right track. You just need to put the counter somewhere, like a global variable, or inside the function's closure.

Comment: @Boundless `removeClass()` with no parameters does remove all classes.

Comment: There is a rogue closing brace in your code, after the `addClass` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/ `removeClass` requires *One or more space-separated classes to be removed from the class attribute of each matched element.*

So with that in mind, your call to removeClass isn't likely removing anything.  If you want to clear out the class, then do `$this.attr('class', '')`

As for a counter, here is my updated JS:

```
    var counter = 0;

    $('#droppableChoking').droppable({
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                ++counter;

                //reuse jQuery object
                var $this = $(this);
                //get object type
                var droppedObject = ui.draggable.data('object');
                //css reset
                $this.attr('class', '');
                $this.addClass("grape" + droppedObject);

                // what to do with counter?  not sure.  Whatever you want.  I'm setting text.  Not sure how you want to use it for the class.
                $this.text(counter);
                }
                //play drop sound
                audioClap.play();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your instruction about `removeClass()` is false. Note in the API that the argument passed to the function is in [] brackets. `elem.removeClass([className])`. This means that the argument is optional. Passing nothing will result in the removal of ALL classes, as the OP intended.

Comment: @ATOzTOA the brace is from when I was trying to do the loop, sorry. But the above works. I was trying to make it a lot harder than it actually was. Thanks Eli!

Comment: @idrumgood You are correct +1.  I thought removeClass did not work without any params.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var drop_count = 0;

$('#droppableChoking').droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        //reuse jQuery object
        var $this = $(this);

        //get object type
        var droppedObject = ui.draggable.data('object');

        //css reset
        $this.removeClass();
        $this.addClass("grape_" + drop_count);
        drop_count++;

        //play drop sound
        audioClap.play();
    }
});
```